# "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0" java error

Tags: java, string, secret-key

i get this error message when i try to break in 2 parts (with "break point" the character "@")

- **part_fixed**
- **part_user**

  a *secret key* ***"final key"*** saved as string.

  ```
         service_codeEncrypted_key = new SecretKeySpec(service_codeEncrypted, 0, 8, "DES");


          System.out.println("");
          System.out.println("Secret code as secret key :" + service_codeEncrypted_key);
          System.out.println("");
          String final_key = "service_codeEncrypted_key";//key has the form xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx@yyyyy
          String[] parts = final_key.split("@") ;
          String part_fixed = parts[0]; // xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
          String part_user = parts[1]; // yyyy
          System.out.println("");             
          System.out.println("Service Code decrypted : " + new String(service_codeDecrypted)); // Print the decrypted Text
          System.out.println("");
          // System.out.println("Code for the card : " + part_user); // Print the decrypted Text          
          System.out.println("Finish!!!"); // Print the decrypted Text
          System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------"); // Print the decrypted Text
          System.out.println("");
          System.out.println("");
  ```

The error as shown in the console in the following :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
        at JEncrytion.main(JEncrytion.java:182)

where line 182 is : String part_fixed = parts[0];

The acual key has the form xxx.xxx.xxxxxx.xxx@yyyyy, and i want all the x's in one part and all the y in the second one.

Any ideas?

Comment: why don't you print the length of the `parts` (System.out.println(parts.length);) before accessing the array elements to see how many elements are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String final_key = "service_codeEncrypted_key";` // here is the problem

Replace with the following

```
String final_key = service_codeEncrypted_key;
```

and consider this one too

```
   String part_fixed ="";
   String part_user ="";
   if(parts!=null){
       part_fixed = parts[0]; // xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
       part_user = parts[1]; // yyyy
   }
```

Comment: Thanx mate, that was actually the problem, which of course created another one (i was silly to thing that a secret key could be saved as a string so easily). Thanx again, silly error, i know.

Answer (score 0):

`final_key` (value = "service_codeEncrypted_key") string does not contain `@` and hence the result of `split`  will be an array of single element i.e the original string. So accesing the second element in that array as mentioned here:

```
parts[1];
```

will throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

The logical problem in your code is that you wanted to assign the `service_codeEncrypted_key` variable to `final_key` but instead you did the string assignment. So as mentioned by **Prabhakaran** in his answer, replace this:

```
String final_key = "service_codeEncrypted_key";
```

with

```
String final_key = service_codeEncrypted_key;
```

Comment: Thanx Juned, just mentioned i save the name of the secter key as a string , and not the secret key itself!

Answer (score 0):

That is right your key doesn't contain '@' symbol.

You need to code something like this.

```
if(final_key.contains("@")){
String[] parts = final_key.split("@") ;
    String part_fixed = parts[0]; // xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    String part_user = parts[1]; // yyyy
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String final_key = "service_codeEncrypted_key";
```

doesn't contain the `@` character and so the `parts[]` has no element.

Try to use

```
String[] parts = service_codeEncrypted_key.split("@");
```

Comment: Thanx a! Your proposal is totally in the right direction, i just get the
JEncrytion.java:181: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method split(java.lang.String)
location: interface javax.crypto.SecretKey
                    String[] parts = service_codeEncrypted_key.split("@");

error, because (of course) this is a secret key and not a string. I will try to convert it first.